# how to export data from devexpress gridview to pdf in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

In my project, I am using devexpress controls in one scenario i want to print entire gridview records to pdf, how to do it, please help me in mvc(devexpress gridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [How to export GridView rows and keep end-user modifications (such as sorting, grouping, filtering, selection)](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=KA18639) KB.